# Do ETags generated on upstream need If-None-Match check? (NGINX)

Tags: nginx, http-headers, etags

(Reposting my post deleted after a year of inactivity)

Let's assume I use `etag off` (and `if_modified_since off` with `add_header Last-Modified ""` to not make redundancy) in NGINX and I generate ETags on upstream (i.e. I'm using `proxy_pass`).

For ETags to be useful they should be accompanied with a check for If-None-Match header. My question is -- as I'm generating ETags upstream, do I need a check for If-None-Match header upstream or will the NGINX's own one work?

I checked the [source code](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/a64190933e06758d50eea926e6a55974645096fd/src/http/modules/ngx_http_not_modified_filter_module.c#L171-L256), but I am unsure when that function is executed and has NGINX already made a request to upstream at the time of executing it...

Comment: Nginx generates and checks etag only for static files. So you have to process all checks yourself in upstream

Comment: I don't see anything in the code about that function that it only works with static files?

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#etag Enables or disables automatic generation of the “ETag” response header field for **static resources**

Comment: It says so about the ETag generation -- but I don't see in docs any mentions about whether If-None-Match checks work for dynamic resources.

Comment: For dynamic resources only upstream knows if it matches or not. Not sure about caching though

Comment: I thought that _theoretically_ NGINX could store ETags from upstream (as part of responses) if `proxy_cache` directive is used and then use them to do the If-None-Match check, but not sure whether this is true in practice (most probably no). Would be great if someone did a test and post an answer.